# here is my code for spinner with dropdownlist:

Tags: android, sqlite, drop-down-menu, spinner

I have spinner in my application .The spinner have drop down list.I want to take the value of the dropdown list from the database .how can i do this ?

here is my code for spinner with dropdownlist:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, selectdefault);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an array to specify which fields you want to display.
You could try this.

```
DatabaseProfileHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseProfileHelper(context);
// create an array to specify which fields we want to display
String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseProfileHelper.colNama };
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txtProfileNama};
Cursor c = dbhelper.getAllProfiles();
dbhelper.UpdateProfile(null);
c.moveToFirst();
startManagingCursor(c);
// create simple cursor adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter ca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,R.layout.profile_spinner_row, c, from, to);
// get reference to our spinner
spinProfile.setAdapter(ca);
```